# Java equivalent of reuseable .Net class library/assembly/dll?

Tags: dll, jar

I am having to do some Java work, having been immersed in .Net/C# for many years. I used to think that a Package was equivalent to a .Net assembly or dll - other SO qus that suggest this get a flat "no" - not the same, and yet the word "package" strongly suggests a packed something that could be shared around.

So, in Java, what IS the equivalent of the shareable DLL/project/assembly/class library? In .Net it is standard practice to reference another local project or a DLL built elsewhere. If I wanted to market MyWonderfulLibrary in .Net, I might deliver a DLL file. Equivalent in Java - a jar file? Is this always called an "archive"? Archive suggests something put away for safe-keeping and rarely accessed....

I'm having problems coming to terms with the terms, so to speak. Does Bean = Class? - another source of confusion...

There is a lot of info on comparing the languages, but any guidance or info that compares/clarifies common terminology in .Net **projects** and Java "projects" (?) would be much appreciated.